# How to Connect to Multiple Google spanner DB running on different host from Spring Boot App

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, google-cloud-spanner

Hi I am trying to connect my spring boot application to multiple google cloud spanner DB. I am able to connect with Single database by making entry in application.yml file. My requirement is tonnect with two spanner database in same application. Please help me.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a little bit more information about how you are connecting to Cloud Spanner, and which frameworks you are using besides Spring Boot. Could you for example share an anonymized version of your application.yml and pom.xml files?

Comment: I am also looking for the same solution

Answer (score 0):

The approach is a lengthy one.
The com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-spanner lib autoconfigures using application.properties

To avoid this,
a. you use spring-cloud-gcp-data-spanner
b. You would have to define the spannerTemplate bean manually

Here is a quick code snippet

```
  @Bean
public com.google.auth.Credentials getCredentials() {

    try {
        return new DefaultCredentialsProvider(Credentials::new).getCredentials();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

@Bean
public SpannerOptions spannerOptions() {
    return SpannerOptions.newBuilder()
            .setProjectId("sab-dev-anciq-ml-gol-8565")
            .setSessionPoolOption(SessionPoolOptions.newBuilder().setMaxSessions(10).build())
            .setCredentials(getCredentials())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Spanner spanner(SpannerOptions spannerOptions) {
    return spannerOptions.getService();
}

@Bean
public DatabaseId databaseId() {
    return DatabaseId.of("your_gcp_project_id",
            "instance_name",
            "db_name");
}

@Bean
public DatabaseClient spannerDatabaseClient(Spanner spanner, DatabaseId databaseId) {
    return spanner.getDatabaseClient(databaseId);
}


@Bean
public SpannerMappingContext spannerMappingContext(Gson gson) {
    return new SpannerMappingContext(gson);
}

@Bean
public SpannerEntityProcessor spannerConverter(SpannerMappingContext mappingContext) {
    return new ConverterAwareMappingSpannerEntityProcessor(mappingContext);
}

@Bean
public SpannerSchemaUtils spannerSchemaUtils(
        SpannerMappingContext spannerMappingContext, SpannerEntityProcessor spannerEntityProcessor) {
    return new SpannerSchemaUtils(spannerMappingContext, spannerEntityProcessor, true);
}

@Bean
public SpannerMutationFactory spannerMutationFactory(
        SpannerEntityProcessor spannerEntityProcessor,
        SpannerMappingContext spannerMappingContext,
        SpannerSchemaUtils spannerSchemaUtils) {
    return new SpannerMutationFactoryImpl(
            spannerEntityProcessor, spannerMappingContext, spannerSchemaUtils);
}

@Bean("hostSpannerTemplate")
public SpannerTemplate spannerTemplateForHostProject(
        DatabaseClient databaseClient,
        SpannerMappingContext mappingContext,
        SpannerEntityProcessor spannerEntityProcessor,
        SpannerMutationFactory spannerMutationFactory,
        SpannerSchemaUtils spannerSchemaUtils) {
    return new SpannerTemplate(
            () -> databaseClient,
            mappingContext,
            spannerEntityProcessor,
            spannerMutationFactory,
            spannerSchemaUtils);
}
```

You can now use spannerTemplateForHostProject as a bean to do your curd ops related to host project

Similiarly using Qualifiers you can now define another spannerTemplate that uses databaseClient2 using qualifier in argument

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to find a solution:

[Documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/index.html#multi-instance-usage)

By creating a custom bean for `DatabaseIdProvider` you can set the projectId, instanceId, and database to whatever you would like. Confirmed to be working the `SpannerRepository` implementation as well.

Here is an example of how you would create your own implementation (how you go about feeding it the projectId, instanceId, and databaseName name is up to you):

```
@Bean
public DatabaseIdProvider databaseIdProvider() {
    return () -> DatabaseId.of("projectId", "instanceId", "databaseName");
}
```

The `DatabaseIdProvider` interface extends `Supplier<DatabaseId>`. `DatabaseId` has a method (`of`) that creates the new `DatabaseId` that you need to connect to a different database/instance.

As an example (might be a terrible implementation, but it was what I got up and running quickly): I have this bean in a class that I am able to call and set the projectId, instanceId, and databaseName. This allows me to change which DB I am pointed to when required (called from a controller which calls a repository, etc).

Hope this helps!